# how to share session data between two angular 2 application

Tags: angular, session, cookies, session-management

I have two angular apps App1 and App2. I want to share App1 session data to App2. The reference, like google we can access all google apps with a single login.

Comment: cookies ? localStorage? Hard to tell without a specific use case.

Comment: I logged in App1 and in my App1's dashboard I have the list of applications. The moment I click on the App2 I should not log in again.

Answer (score 0):

that's the logic in a general way:

When user Logs in, BE assign a temporary token to this login.

if dashboard and app1 BE's are different, db-be passes active tokens to app1-be

*OR BETTER* there will be a centralized BE just to generate session token (see https://www.keycloak.org/ and identity mangement software) where every BE involved search for active tokens.

When user clicks on app1 dashboard button, BE redirects him to something like http://[app1]?token=[hash1234] where token is the user's login token value.

User's app1 frontend is launched, read the token and saves it in localstorage.

When app1 calls BE via rest, normally using an angular interceptor, every call is signed with an header value like `{authentication: bearer [token value]}`, where bearer token is the token wich bearer is already logged in.

BE verifies that the token is already valid (most probably with a call to the identity server) and if so grant access to the called resources.

See JWT Authentication and SSO login.